# Slide in div not reflowing the entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slide

I currently have a javascript generating multiple divs (DOM objects) with sub-menu divs that open if the first div is clicked. These submenus appears using the jQuery slide animation.

Currently, when the divs are spawned, they push lower the rest of the divs that currently exists. I would like them to spawn overlapping the other divs inside the documents.

This is the code that i generated by the DOM generating javascript :

```
<div class="de"></div> //"de" divs are divs that when you click them, the summon their corresponding "ds" div.
<div id="8" class="ds" style="display: block;"></div>
<div class="de"></div>
<div id="10" class="ds" style="display: block;"></div>
```

currently, if i click on the "de" div, the whole page has to reflow, creating slowdowns. I would rather have them overlapping over the existing content.

How can i do that? Can i slide them over the existing content? This is my current css :

```
.de{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 895px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
    border:solid 1px #19365D;
    border-top:hidden 0px #19365D;
    border-left:hidden 0px #19365D;
    border-bottom:hidden 0px #19365D;
    background-image:url('images/TableDegrad.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
.ds{
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 98%;
    min-width: 825px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: 2;
    display:none;
    border:solid 1px #19365D;
    background-image:url('images/TableExpends.png');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-left:0.5%;
    margin-right:0.5%;
    padding-left:0.5%;
    padding-right:0.5%;
}
```

Many thanks for your time, i will really appreciate your help.

Comment: Have you tried removing the float?

Comment: @vsync, you could have provided a suggestion instead of simply bashing.

Comment: @lcoderre - by "bashing" i give him motivation to go learn it, so he will at least shame himself less in public. I do not teach, that is as worse as writing bad code. One must seek learn by himself or he has no future. by asking me to suggest correction, you are slowing my own life down. obviously I do not wish to teach such basics.

Comment: Please be kind to each other. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`.de` would most likely need:

`position: relative;`

and `.ds` would need:

```
position: absolute; 
top: 50px;
left: 0;
z-index: 100;
```

The `.ds` div would need to be nested inside the `.de` div for my approach to  work properly. The key thing here is absolute positioning. If you float all these elements, it will have the effect of "re-flowing" (pushing around) the page as you mentioned.